# Connecting to Cloud SQL (MySQL) through Golang on a live site

Tags: mysql, database, go, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a splash page up and running through Google's App Engine. As of now it is just a page that asks users for their email and name, in order to build an email list. I wanted to store the information on cloud sql, but I cannot seem to get it to work on the live site. As of now I am using MySQLWorkbench to successfully connect to the database on cloud sql and I can input data and submit it which successfully fills in the information to the database on the cloud. I do not receive any connection errors and it works as intended locally on localhost:8080/. I then deployed my changes to app engine and navigate to the site, fill in the information, and hit submit the page hangs and eventually returns a 500 error on my Insert method. This is my first time working with DB on a live site so I cannot understand what the issue is moving from localhost to the live site.

main.go:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Page type
type Page struct {
    Title string
}

type emailListUser struct {
    ID    int
    Name  string
    email string
}

// Connect to DB
func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbUser := "jmcarthur"
    dbPass := "my_password"
    dbName := "tcp(ipFromGoogle:port)/tableName" // Also tried ipFromGoogle:port and ipFromGoogle

    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed connection")
    }

    return db
}

// Handlers
func emailListHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "emailList", &Page{Title: "Welcome to My Site"})
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", emailListHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/insert", Insert)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/css/", fs)
    http.Handle("/fonts/", fs)
    http.Handle("/img/", fs)
    http.Handle("/templates/", fs)

    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

var tpl = func() *template.Template {
    t := template.New("")
    err := filepath.Walk("./", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
            fmt.Println(path)
            _, err = t.ParseFiles(path)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }
        return err
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return t
}()

// Insert function
func Insert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()

    if r.Method == "POST" {
        email := r.FormValue("email")
        name := r.FormValue("name")

        insForm, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO emailList(email_address, name) VALUES(?,?)")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        insForm.Exec(email, name)
        log.Println("INSERT: Email: " + email + " | Name: " + name)
    }

    defer db.Close()
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)
}

/* CREATE TABLE tableName(
    email_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email_address VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (email_id)
); */
```

emailList.html

```
{{define "emailList"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {{template "header" .}}
    <body id="emailListBody" class="text-center">
        <div id="emailListContainer" class="col-12 text-center">
            <img src="./img/picture.png" height="250px" width="250px">
            <h1 class="text-center" id="slogan">slogan</h1>
            <div id="formDiv" class="text-center">
                <form method="POST" action="insert">
                    <label for="email" class="col-12" id="emailLabel">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" required placeholder="johndoe@email.com" id="email" name="email">
                    <label for="name" class="col-12" id="nameLabel">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" required placeholder="John Doe" id="name" name="name">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{template "footer" .}}
{{end}}
```

Tree:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── cloud_sql_proxy
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── css
    │   └── main.css
    ├── emailList.html
    ├── fonts
    │   ├── EuroStyle\ Normal.ttf
    │   ├── EurostileBold.ttf
    │   └── ethnocentric\ rg.ttf
    ├── img
    │   ├── picture.png
    ├── js
    └── templates
        ├── footer.html
        └── header.html
```

As I said I can successfully get it working locally, but cannot for the life of me get it to work on the live site. I have ensured that my IP is whitelisted, I tried connecting with the IP in many different ways with and without the port (as can be seen in main.go), but every time I get `POST mysite  [HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 1857ms]`. I believe my confusion is with cloud sql and allowing any IP to send data to the database, but I could be completely wrong. Please help, thank you!!

Comment: [`sql.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open): *"Open may just validate its arguments **without creating a connection** to the database. **To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping**."* Use `if err := db.Ping(); err != nil { ...` to check if you can actually connect to the remote db.

Comment: @mkopriva hello you were helping me the other day, I fixed a bunch of parts up, but still no luck. I cannot understand why this is such a challenge for me. I am using the exact same connection settings I used to connect MySQLWorkbench to my database successfully. No other error comes up including that message you just asked me to implement.

Comment: Your DB Connection string is nonsensical. Use the correct one.

Comment: @Volker how so (not trying to say you’re wrong I’m genuinely wondering). It worked for my test database and this database locally. I even looked over the documentation for  go-sql-driver and tried it the way they had it there as well.

Comment: @JeremyMcArthur If `db.Ping()` returns no error then your app connects to the db successfully. If `db.Ping()` returns an error then your connection string is incorrect, or your db denies access to your app for some reason. You should also check the error returned from `insForm.Exec`. Also, are none of the `fmt`/`log` statements in your code being rendered in your terminal? For debugging you could add more such statements to figure out exactly at which line your code hangs.

Comment: "ipfromgoogle"  is not  an IP address and "port" not a port number. This could not have worked localy. Or are these _placeholders_ and your actual code uses e.g. 3306  for the port? Note that App-Enginge DB-Connection strings to Cloud SQL typically work via Unix sockets and look like "<user>:<pass>@unix(/cloudsl//<instanceConnectionName>)/<DB-Name>?parseTime=true . Here "/cloudsql" is the default  value value of DB_SOCKET_DIR

Comment: @Volker They are just placeholders. This is the first time I am working with a live site so I was not sure what info I could share. I would be happy to share the ip and port if that will help.

Comment: No, placeholders are fine, just make clear these are placeholders. But you should definitively try the Go code from https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connecting_to

Comment: @Volker I am going through that page now. Can I ask what "DB_SOCKET_DIR" is or where I can find it? Would that just be the IP of my database?

Comment: It tis the environment variable containing the file system path if the directory where the socket used to connect to the DB is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my connection function. The solution that ended up working is shown below.

```
Note: projectID = name of your google cloud project
      cloudSQLInstace = name of the instance you created for cloud SQL
      my_username and my_password come from created user under SQL -> Users
```

```
func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbUser := "my_username"
    dbPass := "my_password"
    dbInstance := "projectID:us-central1:cloudSQLInstace"
    dbName := "emailList"

    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@unix(/cloudsql/"+dbInstance+")/"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed connection")
    }

    return db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is not with you connection strings, the process for App Engine has more to it, such as [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#configuring) for standard or [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible#configuring) for Flex.

Also your /tableName string in variable dbName seems to indicate a table name? Look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connecting_to) example, there's and instance + dbname, no table. An instance is a grouping of database names. If however your code works locally to Cloud SQL with same config, then dismiss this part and look at permissions only.

There's too many possibilities. Please isolate further using public Google docs as testing.